# Resx resource and designer files uncollapsed after added to an asp.net mvc project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Strangely, when I've added resource files into my project, they were not collapsed. Does it matter? how do I make them collapse??

Note it got nothing to do with the .es - it happens also for files without en extra extension.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

**Uncollapsed version:**

[image: Uncollapsed]

**Already existing files, which are collapsed as they should**

[image: Collapsed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete autogenerated file `RegisterRes.es.Designer.vb` and open `RegisterRes.es.resx` by double click in Visual Studio it will generate new `RegisterRes.es.Designer.vb` as you expecting.

Comment: Great. It worked. Just note that I had to also change the `"Access Modifier"` dropdown value (when double clicking on the resx file) to `Public`. Thanks ! :)